# Create a sparkline for the delta between each column of data

Tags: google-sheets

Lets say I have data like so...

```
A     B     C     D     E
50   100   125   175   225
```

I want to create a sparkline that will show the difference between each column

`SPARKLINE( [B-A, C-B, D-C, E-D])`

But, I don't want to make my spreadsheet have 2x the number of rows in order to calculate the intermediate result.

Is there a function that will take a range of cells and return an array after apply some math on the input range?

[image: Compute Data on range of data]

**Edit: Solution proposed worked perfectly... Here's what it looks like when applied.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `arrayformula` to perform operations on arrays, for example

```
=sparkline(arrayformula(B2:E2 - A2:D2))
```

plots the sparkline of differences B2-A2,..., E2-D2.

Comment: Odd, how the arrayformula is inside the sparkline.